# Estimate  using Machin's formula

Tags: c++, mathematics, sfinae

## Overview

Below is a simple program to estimate pi to the full precision of the provided type. It uses
[Machin's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula), but this question is about coding style / choices. It compares the result to `M_PI` from `<cmath>` - best we have in C++17.

## Questions

1. Is my use of `enable_if_t` appropriate and idiomatic?
2. Is the use of `static_cast<T>` for `one_over_5` and `one_over_239` the "best" solution here? Neccesary, and appropriate?
3. How about the use of `decltype`, `::epsilon` and `::digits10`?
4. Accuracy: How about `sign =* -1` and `den += 2.0` and `... = sign * ...`? These are integer operations but use the floating point type.
5. My choice to force the user of `pi<T>()` to specify a `T`?

Note: I know the templates should probably be in header file, but all in one here for simplicity on CR.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> = true>
T arctan(T tan) {
  // fabs(tan) > 1 will not converge
  T num  = tan;
  T den  = 1.0;
  T sign = 1.0;
  T term = num;
  T res  = num;
  while (std::fabs(term) > std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()) {
    num *= tan * tan;
    den += 2.0;
    sign *= -1.0;
    term = sign * num / den;
    res += term;
  }
  return res;
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> = true>
T pi() {
  T one_over_5   = static_cast<T>(1.0) / static_cast<T>(5.0);
  T one_over_239 = static_cast<T>(1.0) / static_cast<T>(239.0);
  return (static_cast<T>(4.0) * arctan<T>(one_over_5) - arctan<T>(one_over_239)) *
         static_cast<T>(4.0);
}

int main() {
  auto pi_float = pi<float>();
  auto pi_double = pi<double>();
  auto pi_long_double = pi<long double>();
  std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<decltype(pi_float)>::digits10)
            << pi_float << '\n'
            << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<decltype(pi_double)>::digits10)
            << pi_double << '\n'
            << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<decltype(pi_long_double)>::digits10)
            << pi_long_double << '\n'
            << M_PI << '\n';
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output - demonstrating that `M_PI` from `<cmath>` is actually incorrect at `long double` precision in the last 2 digits (the correct value is 3.1415926535897932384626433...)

**Note** (unrelated to question, but for future reference): It turns out that the reason `M_PI` is "wrong" is because the `M_PI` macro does not specify a literal `L` for `long double`, and hence the value is rounded to double precision before being displayed. If you put a literal `3.14159265358979323846L` then it is accurate. Usually that is provided as the macro `M_PIl`.

```
3.14159
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979324
3.14159265358979312
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answers to your questions

> Is my use of enable_if_t appropriate and idiomatic?

Yes, it is appropriate, and I believe idiomatic for C++17 as well. In C++20 the idiomatic way would be to use concepts of course.

> Is the use of static_cast for one_over_5 and one_over_239 the "best" solution here? Neccesary, and appropriate?

It's necessary to cast at least a few constants to ensure the expression has the right type. However, in this case I would use the constructor syntax instead, and only do it for the minimum number of constants necessary, to keep the expression concise and legible:

```
return (4 * arctan(T{1} / 5) - arctan(T{1} / 239)) * 4;
```

Also note that you don't need to specify `<T>` here, it can be automatically deduced, and since this is so short there is no need to declare temporary variables `one_over_5` and `one_over_239`.

> How about the use of decltype, ::epsilon and ::digits10?

The use of `T::digits10` is fine here. However, using `T::epsilon()` is always very dangerous. It works here *only* because you are trying to calculate something close to `1`, or if you wanted to calculate the arctangent from a very small number you have the advantage that \$\lim_{x\to 0} \arctan x = x\$. In general, if you want to calculate a value using some converging expansion and want to stop if further steps are no longer giving you any increase in precision, you can do that by checking if there is any change in the floating point value:

```
while (res + std::fabs(term) != res) {...}
```

Or perhaps using `std::nextafter()`, to keep in the spirit of `T::epsilon()`:

```
while (res + std::fabs(term) > std::nextafter(res, res + 1)) {...}
```

Although for `std::nextafter()`, it might even be hard to come up with the correct second argument.

Again, your method works fine in this case, it produces the same output as both methods above.

> Accuracy: How about sign =* -1 and den += 2.0 and ... = sign * ...? These are integer operations but use the floating point type.

Currently those are floating point operations because the left hand side is a floating point type, and if the other side is an integer it would be promoted to the floating point type before the operation is performed. Note that you can replace all the constants in `arctan()` with integers and the result will still be correct.

You could change the type of `sign` and `den` to be an integer type, but it is not necessary. Multiplying floating point `sign` by `-1` will not make it drift away from `1`/`-1` over time, and since integers up to \$2^{24}\$ can be represented [exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e) by a `float`, you will not have any problems with `den` either, unless the loop would run for more than 8388607 iterations, which would mean you have bigger problems.

> My choice to force the user of pi() to specify a T?

It forces the user to give the correct type, which might result in less errors and/or more optimal code. You could consider making it `double` by default:

```
template <typename T = double, ...>
T pi() {...}
```

Note that C++20 introduces `std::pi_v<>` which also doesn't not have a default type.

## Make the functions `constexpr`

You can and should make the functions `constexpr`. Interestingly, the compiler would be free to calculate the results of `pi_float`, `pi_double` and `pi_long_double` at compile time regardless, however GCC and Clang don't without `constexpr`. With `constexpr`, GCC does calculate the result at compile time, but Clang still emits a lot of code.

Comment: Excellent as always, thank you. What I meant by "These are integer operations" was,:I perceived there is a tradeoff here:

Keep them int and the *-1 and +=2 operations are then integer ops, which are both more accurate and possibly faster, but at the cost of a integer => FP conversion on each iteration? 

In hindsight, integer for accuracy over speed is probably better?

Comment: Ah, instead of `T den, sign` have `int den, sign`? It shouldn't matter; `sign` will be always be precise, and `den` will only become imprecise after 4194304 iterations if `T = float`.

Comment: Yes, `sign` (ie both 1, -1) are non-approximate in Base2 right? I was also more concerned about `den`

How did you figure this? 

`den` will only become imprecise after 4194304 iterations if `T = float` ??

Comment: I updated the answer. It's after 8388607 iterations actually, integer values up to 16777216 can be represented exactlty by `float`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e)

Comment: Good. I like the T(1) constructor  - I prefer parens rather than {} in most cases - instead of those static_casts for this stuff. Much more readable and even clang-tidy is quiet as opposed to (T)1 -- "Don't use C-style-casts"

Comment: I would argue a `static_assert` is much more relevant in this case. `enable_if` is primarily used to provide overloads for different type traits. Additionally, using a `static_assert` gives an opportunity for better error messages in case of incorrect template parameters.

Comment: @RIsh It has its pros and cons. I like the better error messages as well, however it has been pointed out to me that `enable_if` allows other templated code to check if there is a valid overload of `arctan`, whereas if you use `static_assert()` you can't do that.

Comment: for a plain `is_floating_point` condition, clang's error message is actually quite good on an `enable_if`: candidate template ignored: requirement
      'std::is_floating_point_v<int>' was not satisfied [with T = int]
constexpr T arctan(T tan) {

Answer (score 0):

Updated code, incorporating @G. Sliepen's feedback.

Also adding a second `arctan()` which uses [Euler's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series) - old one renamed to arctan_taylor()

The new series converges faster and does not require special casing for `abs(tan) > 1`

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> = true>
constexpr T arctan_taylor(T tan) {
  if (std::fabs(tan) > 1) return (tan < 0.0 ? -M_PI_2f64 : M_PI_2f64) - arctan_taylor(1 / tan);
  T num  = tan;
  T den  = 1;
  T sign = 1;
  T term = num;
  T res  = num;
  while (res + std::fabs(term) != res) {
    num *= tan * tan;
    den += 2; // will remain precise for T = float up to 2^(mantissa bits + 1) + 1 = 16,777,217
    sign = -sign;
    term = sign * num / den;
    res += term;
  }
  return res;
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> = true>
constexpr T arctan(T tan) {
  T sum  = 0;
  T prod = 1;
  for (int n = 0; sum + std::fabs(prod) != sum; ++n) {
    prod = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; ++k) 
      prod *= 2 * k * tan * tan / ((2 * k + 1) * (1 + tan * tan)); //  Eulers Series
    sum += prod;
  }
  return tan / (1 + tan * tan) * sum;
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> = true>
constexpr T pi() {
  return (4 * arctan(T(1) / 5) - arctan(T(1) / 239)) * 4;
}

int main() {
  auto pi_float       = pi<float>();
  auto pi_double      = pi<double>();
  auto pi_long_double = pi<long double>();
  std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<decltype(pi_float)>::digits10) << pi_float
            << '\n'
            << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<decltype(pi_double)>::digits10) << pi_double
            << '\n'
            << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<decltype(pi_long_double)>::digits10)
            << pi_long_double << '\n'
            << M_PI << '\n';

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Ah, a rare case where [`std::copysign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/copysign) can be used: `if (std::fabs(tan) > 1) return std::copysign(M_PI_2f64, tan) - arctan_taylor(1 / tan);`

Comment: Looks like the inner `for`-loop in the version using the Euler series is not necessary? Just remove `prod = 1` and replace the loop with `prod *= 2 * (n + 1) * tan * tan / ((2 * n + 3) * (1 + tan * tan));`

Comment: I was directly implementing the formula from linked WP page. Not sure what you mean. The inner loop may run for more than one iteration for each n? The prod is reset to 1 for each inner loop (ie the "pi in the formula)? Maybe I missed something, I haven't looked at it very hard. But I think it's meant to be a "sum of multi-term-products".

The inner loop doesn't run at all for n = 0 . once for n=1, twice for n=2 etc  It gives the right answer. I haven't debugged, traced or optimised it other than that. It's already very fast.

Comment: Love the `std::copysign()` !  That's a new one to me! The new Euler algo actually also benefits from the same `if fabs(tan) > 1`. It will converge for bigger values, but it's much faster to use the `1/tan` property.